# RedirectToAction Not Loading Correct View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirecttoaction

This is a weird one. Probably painfully obvious. :D

I have a View (let's call it `View0.aspx`) that posts a form to a controller action (let's call it `Action1`). Action1 runs and then returns `RedirectToAction("Action2")`, which in turn returns `View("View2")`.

Running it in the debugger, everything looks great (Action2 breakpoint gets hit). The problem is, it never loads `View2.aspx`. `View0.aspx` stays there. I even see the HTTP request for the route that calls Action2, but View2 never loads. I don't even get a refresh Any ideas?

Source below:

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
    public ActionResult Action1()
    {
       // Run action code

       return RedirectToAction("Action2");
    }

public ActionResult Action2()
    {
       // run action code

       return View("View2");
    }
```

Comment: Does a break point in the Action2 method get hit?

Comment: Is there something else going on? For instance, from Action1(), you never return Action2() directly, right? Might be helpful to see more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the issue. I was doing an Ajax post, which explains why it wasn't redirecting. I switched it over to a normal post and it worked. Also, I just noticed a few errors in my OP, which I'm about to fix. Sorry about the confusing post.

Comment: Any idea what to do if you require an ActionLink which does a RedirectToAction at the end of the POST?

Answer (score 0):

"see the HTTP request for View2" - you mean for Action2? You can't request view in MVC. "View0.aspx stays there" - where "there"? Is it plain POST or AJAXified? If it's plain POST and you hit Action2 then browser did already left Action0 page and is going to display the new result - whatever it is. Even error will change the page. So what do you mean by "View0.aspx stays there" - no page refresh? Page refresh but with same View0 content? Are you sure that View0 and View2 look different?